# Hiding attributes per function

Tags: laravel

We can use:

```
protected $hidden = array('attribute');
```

to hide the attributes we don't want to send to our views.

And i found out writing:

```
$this->table = 'table';
```

In a specific function resulted in another that table being used.

But what would we do if we need to hide some attributes in a specific function only?

Kinda like this:

```
$this->hidden = array('attribute1', 'attribute2');
```

That didn't work though.

Answer (score 0):

You should really understand how to use [models.](http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent)

In your model you can set several properties, for example, what table the model should use:

```
protected $table = 'my_users';
```

Or which attribtues of the model will be hidden:

```
protected $hidden = array('password');
```

Or which attributes are fillable (whitelisted), and so protecting from mass assignment vulnerabilities:

```
protected $fillable = array('first_name', 'last_name', 'email');
```

Or which attributes should be blacklisted:

```
protected $guarded = array('id', 'password');
```

So, you're not dealing with these properties/attributes by function, but by class (model).

If you set certain attributes as hidden in a model, they will be hidden from Array or JSON conversions regardless.

Comment: I know how everything works, but doing this would make me end up with like 20 models which isn't ideal for me.

Comment: Having 20 models won't hurt your performance and this is how Laravel is meant to be used. I'm not sure what you want to accomplish, but I'd be more than happy to help. Can you give a little more detail?

Comment: I have 3 tables all related to each other, one called "info" containing some info specific to each user like presenation etc, the other one info_options which has a number that corresponds to the id in info_options_data. Doing this in a model for each would give me 3 models for a really simple thing.

Comment: You could do this with just one or two models. If the info_options and presentation tables have some simple trivial data you could just create a custom attributes on the Users model. Laravel calls these [accessors](http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#accessors-and-mutators).